# jquery equivalent javascript for element.function like $("div").toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and I want to convert some methods to native JavaScript code.

In jQuery we are using like

```
$("div").toggle()
```

Is it possible to convert to JavaScript like

```
document.getElementById("id").callfunction();
```

Comment: No. Not really. But you can write: `myFunctionThatToggles(getElementById("id"))`. Consult the jQuery [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js) if you're curious what all it does.

Comment: Another "i want to use jquery without using jquery" fail.

Comment: @TigOldBitties Not failed. This is a valid question. See my answer.

Comment: @user2864740 OP was asking if he can execute the method in `getElementById("id")`  itself. I hope he already knew what you suggested.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal The point is not that it can't be done. It's that if you want to use jquery, use it. It's open source, optimized and well implemented. Why would you extract functionality like this for no reason.

Comment: @TigOldBitties It's always good to know how things are done. He said he is already using `jQuery`, he just wants to know how he can do the same in raw javascript. Then it's upto him how he utilizes this knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do that. If you are satisfied with the other answers, saying that you have to create new function, and you have to call that. Then go for it.

Otherwise, if you really want to follow the syntax, then it is fairly simple and doable. ( Infact that looks pretty )

This is how you can do it:

```
Element.prototype.toggle = function() { 

    if ( this.style.display == '' || this.style.display == 'block' ) { 
        alert ( "Changing display to NONE ");
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        this.style.display = 'block';
        alert ( "Changing display to BLOCK ");
   }
}
```

*Remember IE8 doesn't support Element Prototype, but Chrome, FF, Safari does.*

**Run it**

1. Open chrome console in this page.
2. copy-paste above code, and run in
   console.
3. Now execute this in console `document.getElementById('question-header').toggle()`    [ This will
   show/hide the question title in this page ]

Answer (score 2):

Don't clearly understood what you want  but if this helps :

```
function toggle_item(id){        //  your div id
  var this_item = document.getElementById(id); 
  if( this_item.style.display == 'block' ) {
    this_item.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    this_item.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html:-**

```
   <button onclick="toggleCheck('contentDiv')">Toggle</button>
   <div ID="contentDiv" style="display:block;">This is content.</div>
```

**Javascript: -**

```
function toggleCheck(divId) {
  var divId = document.getElementById(divId);
  // Toggle 
  divId.style.display == "block" ? divId.style.display = "none" : 
  divId.style.display = "block"; 
}
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ihIpEmuL/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Of cause yes. You need to implement a function callfunction. Then add this function as prototype function of the element . For details, please look at below sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">Hello, world!</div>
  <button onclick="test()">toggle</button>
  <script>
    var test = function() {
      document.getElementById("test").callfunction();
    };


    var callfunction = function() {
      if (this.style.display == "none") {
        this.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        this.style.display = "none";
      }
    };


    // set callfunction as prototype function of all elements 
    Element.prototype.callfunction = callfunction;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

After testing, this can work in IE8, IE9, chrome and ff.