# How to make expandable and collapsable by click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

Please suggest me how to make expandable and collapsable with (+ and -) by a click with the following javascript. so if i click on pen it will expand and again click on pen it will collapse. And all these this needs to be done with JavaScript not with Jquery.

Take a look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/1/).

```
var dataSource = ({
        "Pen": ({
            "Cello": ({
                "C1": ({}),
                "C2": ({})
            }),
                "Parker": ({
                "P1": ({}),
                "P2": ({})
            })
        })
    }),
        traverseObject = function (obj) {
            var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
                li;
            for (var prop in obj) {
                li = document.createElement("li");
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
                if (typeof obj\[prop\] == "object" && Object.keys(obj\[prop\]).length) {
                    li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj\[prop\]));
                }
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
            return ul;
        };


    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery in peudo code

      `$(button-element).click (function (){
            $ (element-to-collapse).toggle ();
      });`


Edit: i'currently with the android so client and after i save the message i lost line break and indentation

To transkate it in simple javascript

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138532/jquery-equivalent-javascript-for-element-function-like-div-toggle)

Comment: No Jquery...only javascript

Comment: @user3237973 i completed the askwer